# Umbraco create macro of .NET Composite Control

Tags: vb.net, umbraco, composite-controls

Been struggling with this for a while now..

I'm perfectly able to create a working .NET Composite-control, which works fine in an aspx website.

I'm able to create in umbraco a macro for a .net homemade user control and pass parameters to it, this works fine on the umbraco-website as well.

Problem is the combination of both. I would like to create a macro in umbraco for the composite control I've created, but I'm not able to get it right.

Here I chose '.NET Custom Control' because my composite-control is a vb.class only (and the '.NET user control needs an .ascx page) As Assembly I chose the name of the dll (without the extension As Type I took 'NAMESPACE.CLASSNAME'

But then I'm getting this error:

```
'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at umbraco.developer.assemblyBrowser.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)'
```

[image]

What I'm doing wrong here?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with .dll in assembly name? also whats is your namespace and name of the class?

Regards

Isamil